# 404 not found when trying to run Api Controller function from ASP.NET core 5 web app

Tags: c#, controller, razor-pages, asp.net-apicontroller, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to create an API controller in my ASP.NET core 5 Razor Pages web application.

I have created the Api Controller inside a folder named `Api` in Visual studio.

Then when I try to run the following url to test that the api controller works, I get a 404 not found:

`https://localhost:345345/api/saveimage`

What am I missing?

**Api Controller (SaveImageController.cs):**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class saveImageController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "test", "test2" };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though using folder "Api" for your controller will work, it is normal to keep controllers inside a folder called "Controllers".

Please note that Razor pages are using folder based routing, the same does not apply to controllers.

In Startup#ConfigureServices, make sure you have this:

```
services.AddControllers();
```

In Startup#Configure, make sure you have this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! for some reason all the guides I checked failed to mention this